# remove unnecessary line feeds from file

Tags: c#, regex

I am reading an input text file in C# code. The file has column delimiter as '|' and row delimiter as '\n'. Following is the test data -

```
1001 | Name | XYZ | Department1 Roll no 1. (\r\n)
1002 | Name | ABC | Department2 Roll No 2. (\r\n)
1003 | Name | PQR | Department3 (\r\n)
Roll (\r\n)
no3. (\r\n)
1004 | Name | MNO | Department4 Roll No 4. (\r\n)
1005 | Name | DEF | Department5 Roll No 5. (\r\n)
```

First two records are in correct format. However, third record got inserted incorrectly. I would like to format it as per other records which I have.

I have written C# code for this as shown below -

```
string text = File.ReadAllText(inputfile);
text = text.Replace(@"\r\n", " ");
File.WriteAllText(ouutputfile, text);
```

However, its not working for me. Can anybody help me out with this?

More sample data - 
[image]

Can we have a regular expression for this?

Comment: It sounds like your question is "how do I remove line feeds from a text file with C#" (which, by the way, I'm sure has been answered before if you googled it).

Comment: I do not want to remove all the line feeds. Rather, just the problematic ones.

Comment: Two things: 1) you say that the file has "\n"s in it but don't mention "\r"s so why are you trying to replace them? 2) What logic do you have to work out which ones to replace and which ones not? I assume the row delimiters shouldn't be removed...

Comment: Use [FileReadAllLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of ReadAllText. It will return you all lines and then you can process them. Check whether the line has a correct format and combine it with the previous one if it's not formatted as you want

Comment: Do you still need help with this?  You've not accepted an answer.

Comment: Yeah Mike. I need a regular expression for this.

Answer (score 1):

Process in reverse, using `File.ReadAllLines`, as Sergii commented. This will let you check each line to see if it matches the expected format or if the line was created as a result of an incorrect linefeed.  If the current line was the result of a misplaced linefeed, then you can simply append it to the previous line for your resulting output.

```
static void ProcessFile(string inputfile, string outputfile)
{
    // Read the files by lines.
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(inputfile);

    // We'll process in reverse, so create a stack (LIFO) for the results.
    Stack<string> results = new Stack<string>();

    // Process each line, checking that if it doesn't match the format, then we append to previous line.
    string resultLine = "";
    for (int i = lines.Length - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        resultLine = lines[i] + resultLine;
        int lineParts = resultLine.Split('|').Count();
        if (lineParts == 4) // Well-formatted line.
        {
            results.Push(resultLine);
            resultLine = "";
        }
        else if (lineParts < 4) // An invalid linefeed from the previous entry.
        {
            // We prepend a space to replace the linebreak; then just continue through loop, where the current line will be appended to previous.
            resultLine = " " + resultLine;
        }
        else // lineParts > 4... unexpected
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("What to do here?");
        }
    }

    // Now that all our lines have been fixed, write them back out.
    File.WriteAllLines(outputfile, results.ToArray());
}
```

Note: This isn't the most efficient, as you'll have to be sure your files to process are small enough to fit in memory essentially 3 times, but that's only 1 time more than your original solution.  If your files are large, you'll probably want to modify the solution to operate on streams instead of holding it all it local variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = File.ReadAllText(inputfile);
var rawParts = text.Split(new string[] { "\n" });
var proParts = new List<string>(rawParts.Take(2));
proParts.Add(rawParts[2] + " " rawParts[3] + " " rawParts[4]);
proParts.AddRange(rawParts.Skip(5));
var sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var part in proParts)
  sb.Append(part + "\n");
File.WriteAllText(outputfile, sb.ToString());
```

Comment: I think the OP will want a more of a generic approach to this problem, not a hard coded "one time" use method

Comment: replcaed with Regex.Split(text, @"\r\n");. Still no luck

Comment: To TheLethaCode: TDD much?